# Laravel sync not working with empty array

Tags: php, laravel

I've a method looks like this:

```
public function saveContacts(Request $request)
{
    if($request->contacts) {
        $contacts = collect($request->contacts)->pluck('id');
        $this->contacts()->sync($contacts->toArray());
    }
}
```

It's working but if `$request->contacts` is an empty array it does not remove all records. What could be the case here?

Comment: What's `contacts()` here?

Comment: ```contacts()``` is a ```belongsToMany``` relation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if ($request->contacts) {
    $contacts = collect($request->contacts)->pluck('id')->toArray();
    if (empty($contacts)) {
        $this->contacts()->detach();
    } else {
        $this->contacts()->sync($contacts);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will throw an error: ```Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::formatRecordsList() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/forum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php on line 894```

Comment: I don't see `format‌​RecordsList()` in Laravel, so I guess it's one of your app's relations and the error is not related to this code.

Comment: It's working now. The ```else``` should look like this: ```$this->contacts()->sync($contacts->toArray());``` thanks for helping me.