# Laravel observer for pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, observers

I've got a observer that has a update method:

**ObserverServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    Relation::observe(RelationObserver::class);
}
```

**RelationObserver.php**

```
public function updated(Relation $relation)
{
    $this->cache->tags(Relation::class)->flush();
}
```

So when I update a relation in my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, Relation $relation)
{
     $relation->update($request->all()));
     return back();
}
```

Everything is working as expected. But now I've got a pivot table. A **relation** `belongsToMany` products.

So now my controller method looks like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Relation $relation)
{
    if(empty($request->products)) {
        $relation->products()->detach();
    } else {
        $relation->products()->sync(collect($request->products)->pluck('id'));
    }

    $relation->update($request->all());

    return back();
}
```

The problem is that the observer is not triggered anymore if I **only** add or remove products.

How can I trigger the observer when the `pivot table` updates aswel?

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, you shouldn't need to have the if statement in the controller as `$relation->products()->sync(collect($request->products)->pluck('id'));` will simply detach the products for you if `$request->products` is empty or null.

Comment: @RossWilson I guess that's not true. I receive an error if array is ```[]```. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489712/laravel-sync-not-working-with-empty-array

Comment: I think this would be considered a mass update, Laravel does not fire the `saved()` and `updated()` model events for mass updates - because the model isn't actually retrieved. [See the notice under Mass Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

Comment: @RossWilson sorry you're right thanks

Comment: @Yat23 hmmm so it's not possible I guess.

Comment: Yeah, it use to be an issue but it was changed in 5.3.29 :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you already know, Laravel doesn't actually retrieve the models nor call save/update on any of the models when calling `sync()` thus no event's are created by default. But I came up with some alternative solutions for your problem.

---

1 - To add some extra functionality to the sync() method:

If you dive deeper into the `belongsToMany` functionality you will see that it tries to guess some of the variable names and returns a BelongsToMany object. Easiest way would be to make your relationship function to simply return a custom `BelongsToMany` object yourself:

```
public function products() {

    // Product::class is by default the 1. argument in ->belongsToMany calll
    $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance(Product::class);

    return new BelongsToManySpecial(
        $instance->newQuery(),
        $this,
        $this->joiningTable(Product::class), // By default the 2. argument
        $this->getForeignKey(), // By default the 3. argument
        $instance->getForeignKey(), // By default the 4. argument
        null // By default the 5. argument
    );
}
```

Or alternatively copy the whole function, rename it and make it return the `BelongsToManySpecial` class. Or omit all the variables and perhaps simply return `new BelongsToManyProducts` class and resolve all the BelongsToMany varialbes in the `__construct`... I think you got the idea.

Make the BelongsToManySpecial class extend the original BelongsToMany class and write a sync function to the BelongsToManySpecial class.

```
public function sync($ids, $detaching = true) {

    // Call the parent class for default functionality
    $changes = parent::sync($ids, $detaching);

    // $changes = [ 'attached' => [...], 'detached' => [...], 'updated' => [...] ]
    // Add your functionality
    // Here you have access to everything the BelongsToMany function has access and also know what changes the sync function made.

    // Return the original response
    return $changes
}
```

Alternatively override the `detach` and `attachNew` functions for similar results.

```
protected function attachNew(array $records, array $current, $touch = true) {
    $result = parent::attachNew($records, $current, $touch);

    // Your functionality

    return $result;
}

public function detach($ids = null, $touch = true)
    $result = parent::detach($ids, $touch);

    // Your functionality

    return $result;
}
```

If you want to dig deeper and want to understand what's going on under the hood then analyze the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationship` trait - specifically the `belongsToMany` relationship function and the `BelongsToMany` class itself.

---

2 - Create a trait called `BelongsToManySyncEvents` which doesn't do much more than returns your special BelongsToMany class

```
trait BelongsToManySyncEvents {

    public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null) {

        if (is_null($relation)) {
            $relation = $this->guessBelongsToManyRelation();
        }

        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);
        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
        $relatedKey = $relatedKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();

        if (is_null($table)) {
            $table = $this->joiningTable($related);
        }

        return new BelongsToManyWithSyncEvents(
            $instance->newQuery(), $this, $table, $foreignKey, $relatedKey, $relation
        );
    }

}
```

Create the `BelongsToManyWithSyncEvents` class:

```
class BelongsToManyWithSyncEvents extends BelongsToMany {

    public function sync($ids, $detaching = true) {

        $changes = parent::sync($ids, $detaching);

        // Do your own magic. For example using these variables if needed:
        // $this->get() - returns an array of objects given with the sync method
        // $this->parent - Object they got attached to
        // Maybe call some function on the parent if it exists?

        return $changes;
    }

}
```

Now add the trait to your class.

---

3 - Combine the previous solutions and add this functionality to every Model that you have in a BaseModel class etc. For examples make them check and call some method in case it is defined...

```
$functionName = 'on' . $this->foreignKey . 'Sync';

if(method_exists($this->parent), $functionName) {
    $this->parent->$functionName($changes);
}
```

---

4 - Create a service

Inside that service create a function that you must always call instead of the default `sync()`. Perhaps call it something attachAndDetachProducts(...) and add your events or functionality

---

As I didn't have that much information about your classes and relationships you can probably choose better class names than I provided. But if your use case for now is simply to clear cache then I think you can make use of some of the provided solutions.

Comment: thanks for your time and great explanation. I've got it working now with an elegant solution! +1 for that :)

Comment: There's a much simpler answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400590/1378927

Answer (score 10):

When I search about this topic, it came as the first result.
However, for newer Laravel version you can just make a "Pivot" model class for that.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class PostTag extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'post_tag';

    public $timestamps = null;
}
```

For the related model

```
public function tags(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->using(PostTag::class);
}
```

and you have to put your declare your observer in `EventServiceProvider`
as stated in [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers)

```
PostTag::observe(PostTagObserver::class);
```

Reference: [Observe pivot tables in Laravel](https://mayahi.net/laravel/observe-pivot-tables-in-laravel/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
public $afterCommit = true;
```

at the beginning of the observer class.. It will wait until the transactions are done, then performs your sync which should then work fine..

Please check [Laravel's documentation for that](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers-and-database-transactions).

It seems this solutions was just added in Laravel 8.