# Laravel observer not attaching on pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a `Category` Model which has a parent relation to itself:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

and a ManyToMany relation to `FieldCategory`

```
public function fieldcategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\FieldCategory');
}
```

And I have a `CategoryObserver` to observe if there are any changes of parent (ex. if a category was moved to subcategory) if threre was a change I want to attach parent `FielCategory` entries to subcategory

```
public function updated(Category $category)
{
    if($category->parent_id != null) {
        $this->updateFieldCategories($category);
    }
}
public function updateFieldCategories(Category $category)
{

    $category->fieldcategories()->detach();

    $parent = \App\Models\Category::find($category->parent->id);

    $parentFieldCategoriesArray = [];
    foreach ($parent->fieldcategories as $parentCat)
    {
        $parentFieldCategoriesArray[] = $parentCat->id;
    }
    $category->fieldcategories()->attach($parentFieldCategoriesArray);
}
```

And it works fine on `updated`! But when I try to do exact thing on `created` (when it has parent selected) it fails, and I have no idea why?
I've try to debug this function and `$parentFieldCategoriesArray` is filled with necessary ID's. It looks like the `$category->fieldcategories()->attach()` method is not firing and I don't know why.
There are no records in the pivot table on `created` and on `updated` it works fine.
I'm using Laravel 5.6

Any help please?

UPDATE:
As requested this is my created function

```
public function created(Category $category)
{
    \Log::debug('PARENT: '.$category->parent_id);
    if($category->parent_id != null) {
        $this->updateFieldCategories($category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the parent is assigned properly to the newly created category? Also, can you show us your created function for your observer?

Comment: I've updated the question to show you my `created` function. Yes I'm sure the parent is assigned properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this question 1 year ago. See this: [Laravel observer for pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103552/laravel-observer-for-pivot-table).

2 options here. Create a custom `BelongsToMany` or create a custom trait `BelongsToManySyncEvents`.

Please see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103552/laravel-observer-for-pivot-table).

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
public $afterCommit = true;
```

at the beginning of the observer class.. It will wait until the transactions are done, then save your attaching or detaching..

Please check [Laravel's documentation for that](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers-and-database-transactions).